# Unknown plant/tree in the garden

Tags: identification

These plants started growing in my garden a few weeks ago:

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

There are several of these, all growing in the same planter, which make me think it's something that we put there but can't remember planting anything like that.

Comment: Cosmos? Unless you planted fennel seeds

Comment: No, it's not fennel

Comment: Pretty sure it's cosmos too. The pink base of the branching stems is what cosmos has if it has the typical pink-magenta flowers

Comment: Is it some wild flower or you have to plant it?

Comment: Usually you need to plant the seeds

Comment: I vote Cosmos as well!  Did you use seed?

Comment: @stormy apparently... We don't remember planting those

Comment: I'd go get some petunias, already started in 4" pots or something similar.  Are you using fertilizer?  Those little guys don't look like they'll get anywhere fast.  If just a couple of errant cosmos seed are that vigorous something is off kilter here.

Comment: They came to that size from nothing in about two weeks

Answer (score 5):

I've just realised you're in the UK - these plants are Cosmos, but quite how they got there I'm not sure. If you had some last year, it's possible the seeds germinated by themselves because we had hot weather in April, so maybe they grew from those, but usually, Cosmos seeds need heat to germinate in the UK so they're started off in seed trays or modules, in a greenhouse or indoors. They're only half hardy here too, which means they're not usually planted out as small plants until mid to end of May.